# VSCODE autocomplete deletes the text

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

My VSCODE sometimes insert sometimes replace the text when im working with flutter. There are some screenshots of the problem. When i use control + space it inserts the text like i wanted. But sometimes when i am writing it gives me the completation when i click it it replaces.

[This is does not replace this inserts the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm2Q7.png)

[This doesnt not insert this replaces the rest of the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hgUY.png)

Comment: this drives me crazy too.